# Azure Service Fabric basic cluster requires 6 vCPU quota

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am new to Azure and have started experimenting with Service Fabric using a free account. I am running into an issue following the tutorial (found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/quickstart-managed-cluster-portal) whereby apparently I do not have enough vCPU quota in my region to start a basic cluster. I used all default values to start the Basic cluster.

```
ErrorCode: QuotaExceeded ErrorMessage: Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved Total Regional Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: GermanyWestCentral, Current Limit: 4, Current Usage: 0, Additional Required: 6, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 6
```

I tried requesting a quota increase but my request was unsuccessful. Could anyone provide some insight as to why there is a minimum of 6 vCPUs to start a basic cluster? I would have hoped if I only want to experiment with one or two nodes I wouldn't need as many vCPUs. Can I control somewhere the number of vCPUs used by each node of the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution. The cluster requires at least 3 nodes, so I configured it to use the node type Standard_D1_v2 instead of the default one which uses only 1 vCPU.